# Problems with the Geometric Series Factored

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, summation

Consider the geometric series generated by 1/(1-x).If I were to factor the series out I would get $$\frac{1}{1-x}= (1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)(1+x^8)...(1+x^{2^n}) ...$$Suppose I were to take the natural logarithm of both sides I would get the following:
$$-\ln(1-x)= \ln(1+x)+\ln(1+x^2)+\ln(1+x^4)+...\ln(1+x^{2^n})+...$$ Let $x=-1$; I would get
$$-\ln(2)=\ln(0)+\ln(2)+\ln(2)...$$

But this should be wrong because the ln(0) is infinity. What's going on?

Comment: $\ln 0$ is $-\infty$, and you add an infinite number of $\ln 2$. The World is safe.

Comment: ^Yes... I know. The result is ridiculous, but what math rules were violated in the process of getting this?

Comment: Come on, nobody allows you to write $\ln 0$, not even to think of it.

Comment: Then what went wrong with the process?

Comment: You cannot set $x=-1$.

Comment: ^If it's because of the ridiculous result, then I understand and agree. However I don't see why I can't set it to x=-1 due to the power series generated being convergent.

Comment: Why do you believe that the infinite product converges ?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the identity you wrote is incorrect. It is the case that
$$
(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)\dotsb(1+x^{2^n})
=\frac{1-x^2}{1-x}\times\frac{1-x^4}{1-x^2}\times\dotsb\times\frac{1-x^{2^{n+1}}}{1-x^{2^n}}=\frac{1-x^{2^{n+1}}}{1-x}\tag{1}
$$
so
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\log(1+x^{2^i})=\log(1-x^{2^{n+1}})-\log(1-x);\quad (-1<x<1)
$$
where the restriction is necessary so that the log laws hold.

Comment: ^That doesn't make sense though because if I were to do what you said, I would get the natural logarithm of a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to go too far to get a surprize out of $$\frac{1}{1-x}= (1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)(1+x^8)...(1+x^{2^n})$$

Let $x=-1$ and you get  $$ 1/2 =0 $$

The problem is with the interval of convergence of $$
\frac {1}{1-x} = 1+x+x^2+... $$

Comment: ^Wait... I took the natural logarithm of both sides though.So it should be convergent due to the power series generated.

Comment: ^Yes. I am sure.

Comment: ^By the way, by taking the natural logarithm of 1/(1-x), don't you also have to take the natural logarithm of both ends of the interval?

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises for all $n$. For $n=0$. You get $\,(1-x^2)/(1-x) = (1+x\,)$ which is true for all $\,x\neq 1.\,$ If $\,x=-1\,$ then you have $\,0=0.\,$ Now $\,\log 0\,$ is undefined but equation is  true. The next case for $n=1$ you get $\,(1-x^4)/(1-x) =(1+x)(1+x^2)\,$ and now if $\,x=-1\,$ you have $0=0$ and you still have $\log 0$ problem. In general $\, (1-x^{2^{n+1}})/(1-x) = (1+x)(1+x^2)\cdots(1+x^{2^n})\,$ and for $\,x=-1\,$ you still have $\log 0$ problems. In the limit, $\,x^{2^{n+1}} \to 0\,$ but **only** if $\,|x|<1.$

An interpretation of the equation $\, 1 + x + x^2 + \dots + x^{2^{n+1}-1} =
 (1+x)(1+x^2) \cdots (1+x^{2^n}) \,$ is that every integer $\, 0 <= k < 2^{n+1} \,$ has a unique binary representation as a sum of powers of $2$ using $\, 2^0, 2^1, 2^2, \dots, 2^n. \,$ If
$\, x \neq 1 \,$ then the left side of the equation equals $\, (1-x^{2^{n+1}})/(1-x). \,$

Comment: ^But 1/(1-x) is what I wrote: Not (1+x).

Comment: Note that the identity you wrote is incorrect. You are missing the needed numerator. I supplied it so the equatoin is correct.

Comment: ^Wait... I don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

The proof of the infinite product relies on identities of the form

$$(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7.$$

For $x=-1$,

$$(1-1)(1+1)(1+1)=1-1+1-1+1-1+1-1$$ still holds but nothing allows you to equate it to

$$\frac1{1-(-1)}$$ "in the limit".

For the same reason that

$$1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7+\cdots=\frac1{1-x}$$ is only valid for $|x|<1$.